# Loading JSON file from another directory in Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read in a JSON file called league.json from a python file called run_test.py. The JSON file is in a different directory. I am running Windows 10 and python 3.8.6 in Visual Studio.

- The directory I'm running the python file in is: C:\Users\my_un\Documents\folder1\folder2\model\run_test.py
- The directory I am trying to load the json file from is:
  C:\Users\my_un\Documents\folder1\folder2\config\league.json

Based on documentation I've found, the below code should work, but I keep getting the error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config\league.json'.

This does run successfully when I move league.json to the same directory as the python file, and change the open location to: '.\league.json'.

What am I doing wrong? My code is below. Thanks in advance.

```
import json

with open('.\config\league.json', 'r') as f:
    config = json.load(f)

print (len(config))
```

Comment: change the path to `open('..\config\league.json', 'r')` , by adding one more `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the path to `open('..\config\league.json', 'r')` , by adding one more `.`

if the above doesn't work, use `abspath` to find the path of  `league.json` and pass in the `open(path)` function

Comment: Using open('..\config\league.json', 'r') worked... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The folder 'config' needs to be in the folder 'model' for your code to run. Otherwise change your code to

```
open('C:\Users\my_un\Documents\folder1\folder2\config\league.json', 'r')
```